# Cant write simple insert query postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, insert

I don't understand why this query doesn't work.

I've tried change s to "s", n_post to "n_post" and both of that. It didn't help me.

My table looks like:

[image]

```
INSERT INTO s ( n_post, name, reiting, town) VALUES 
  ( 'S1', 'Смит', 20, 'Лондон'),
  ( 'S2', 'Джонс', 10, 'Париж'),
  ( 'S3', 'Блейк', 30,  'Париж'),
  ( 'S4', 'Кларк', 20,  'Лондон'),
  ( 'S5', 'Адамс', 30,  'Париж');
```

But every time I got error like:

> ERROR:  column "n_post" of relation "s" does not exist LINE 1: INSERT
>   INTO s ( n_post, name, reiting, town) VALUES

Thanks for everyone, problem was solved. I droped database, and create it again.

Comment: Your table doesn't have a column with that name.  There is nothing mysterious about the error.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thx for answer, but my table has that column

Comment: Is your table's name `s`?

Comment: @forpas thx for answer, yes table name is s

Comment: Did you try @i.bondarenko 's answer?

Comment: @forpas yes, but nothing changed(

Comment: Try: `INSERT INTO s VALUES ....` without specifying the columns. If this works then there is a problem with the name(s) of the column(s).

Comment: Can you create a www.sqlfiddle.com?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your field n_post has a leading space. Try " n_post" or rename the column.

Comment: Could you add create table script? Probably there is not a space but an another char.

Comment: Alternatively could you drop and recreate a field name it f1.